# How can I dump ALL of a contact's phone numbers?

Tags: android

I can't figure this out... I'm using Android 2.1 SDK

**BUG:**
*this will dump all the contacts' phone numbers ***except*** for CUSTOM LABEL phone numbers...*

How can I get it to dump phone numbers that have custom labels also?

So, for example 1 of my contacts has 3 phone numberss... 2 with custom label.. so for that contact only 1 phone number will be dumped to the log.

To **run**, just call `DumpContacts.readContacts(this);` from any Activity.

```
package com.abc.debug;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;

public class DumpContacts {
        private static final String TAG = "Dump Contacts";

        static public void readContacts(Context context)
        {
            String contactId, hasPhone, phoneNumber;
            ContentResolver cr=context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor phones, cc = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
            while (cc.moveToNext())
            {
                contactId = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                hasPhone = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                int nameFieldColumnIndex = cc.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
                String contactName = cc.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
                Log.v(TAG, "Contact id="+contactId+" name="+contactName);
                if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhone)==1)
                {
                    // You know it has a number so now query it like this
                    phones = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null);
                    while (phones.moveToNext())
                    {
                        phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        String label=getPhoneLabel(context, phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE)),
                                phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL)));
                        Log.v(TAG, "  Phone"+phoneNumber+" with label="+label);
                    }
                    phones.close();
                }
            }
            cc.close();
        }

        static private String getPhoneLabel(Context context, int type, String label)
        {
            String s;
            switch(type)
            {
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                    s = "home_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    s = "mobile_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                    s = "work_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_FAX_WORK:
                    s = "fax_work_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_FAX_HOME:
                    s = "fax_home_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_PAGER:
                    s = "pager_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER:
                    s = "other_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CALLBACK:
                    s = "callback_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CAR:
                    s = "car_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_COMPANY_MAIN:
                    s = "company_main_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_ISDN:
                    s = "isdn_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MAIN:
                    s = "main_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER_FAX:
                    s = "other_fax_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_RADIO:
                    s = "radio_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_TELEX:
                    s = "telex_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_TTY_TDD:
                    s = "tty_tdd_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE:
                    s = "work_mobile_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_PAGER:
                    s = "work_pager_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_ASSISTANT:
                    s = "assistant_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MMS:
                    s = "mms_phone";
                    break;
                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM:
                    if(label == null)
                        s = "custom";
                    else
                        s = "custom:" + label;
                    break;
                default:
                    s = "default";
            }
            return s;
        }

}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html

Comment: Your sample code dumps custom phone numbers for me just fine.  For what it's worth I'm using Android 2.3.7, CyanogenMod-7.1.0-Desire (on HTC Desire).

Comment: interesting... I just tried it on my phones... they both work... but they both have gingerbread like you. So either it's a problem with the VM (doubtful) or Android 2.1 (more likely) (my VM Runs 2.1). Well at least I know not everyone using my app will have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this one. i have tested this code.

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
Cursor cur=cr.query(uri, null, null, null, sortOrder);
    if(cur.getCount()>0){
    while(cur.moveToNext()){


        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)))> 0) {
//get the phone number
                Cursor phoneCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);
                while (phoneCur.moveToNext()) {
               String phoneNumber= phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                int phonetype = phoneCur.getInt(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                String customLabel = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL));
               String phoneLabel = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.getTypeLabel(this.getResources(), phonetype, customLabel);                       
                Log.e(TAG, "Phone Number: " + phoneNumber + " Selected Phone Label: " + phoneLabel);
                                    }phoneCur.close();
}              
        }
    } cur.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
    static public void readContacts(Context context)
    {
        String contactId, hasPhone, phoneNumber;
        ContentResolver cr=context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor phones, cc = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        if (cc.moveToFirst()) {
        do
        {
            contactId = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            hasPhone = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
            int nameFieldColumnIndex = cc.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String contactName = cc.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
            Log.v(TAG, "Contact id="+contactId+" name="+contactName);
            if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhone)==1)
            {
                // You know it has a number so now query it like this
                phones = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext())
                {
                    phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String label=getPhoneLabel(context, phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE)),
                            phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL)));
                    Log.v(TAG, "  Phone"+phoneNumber+" with label="+label);
                }
                phones.close();
            }
        } while (cc.moveToNext());
        }cc.close();
    }
```

Comment: moveToFirst or getCount or any other method call is necessary for the cursor to get initialized as resolver.query only constructs the cursor query internally, it is the first operation call on the cursor like moveToFirst or getCount which actually fetches the data

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a few helper classes:

```
/**
* Represents a RawContact (NOTE: This is not the same as a Contact)
* Think of this as an outer join of the raw_contacts table with the data table
*/
public class RawContact {
    public String Name;
    public int ContactId;
    public List<PhoneNumber> Phones;
}

/**
* Represents a high level PhoneNumber from the phone table
*/
public class PhoneNumber {
    public String Number;
    public int Type;
    public String Label;
}
```

These allow us to store the relevant information we are looking for. Then, I would use the `android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContactsEntity` to look for all the raw contacts and their phone numbers. NOTE: One Contact can have multiple RawContacts so plan accordingly (this sample does not take this into account).

```
package com.contactsample.android;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContactsEntity;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Data;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DumpContacts {

    public static final String TAG = "DumpContacts";

    public static void readContacts(Context context) {
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        String[] projection = new String[] {
            RawContactsEntity._ID, // this is the Raw Contacts ID
            RawContactsEntity.CONTACT_ID,
            RawContactsEntity.DATA_ID, // the data id
            Data.MIMETYPE,
            Data.DATA1,
            Data.DATA2,
            Data.DATA3,
            Data.DATA4,
            Data.DATA5
        };
        String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? OR " + Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
            Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
            StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
        };
        Uri uri = RawContactsEntity.CONTENT_URI;
        Log.v(TAG, "Fetching from " + uri);
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        int oldContactId = -1;
        RawContact current = null;
        List<RawContact> contacts = new ArrayList<RawContact>();
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                final int rawContactId = cursor.getInt(0);
                final int contactId = cursor.getInt(1);
                final int dataId = cursor.getInt(2);
                final String mimeType = cursor.getString(3);
                if (oldContactId != contactId) {
                    current = new RawContact();
                    current.ContactId = contactId;
                    oldContactId = contactId;
                    contacts.add(current);
                }
                Log.v(TAG, "ContactID: " + contactId);
                if (mimeType.equals(StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                    current.Name = cursor.getString(4);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Name: " + current.Name);
                } else if (mimeType.equals(Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                    if (current.Phones == null) {
                        current.Phones = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();
                    }
                    PhoneNumber phone = new PhoneNumber();
                    phone.Number = cursor.getString(4);
                    phone.Type = cursor.getInt(5);
                    phone.Label = cursor.getString(6);
                    current.Phones.add(phone);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Number: " + phone.Number + " Type: " + phone.Type + " Label: " + phone.Label);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "Found " + contacts.size() + " contacts");
    }
}
```

This works for me on the emulator using an Android 2.1 AVD.

What it does is get each RawContact's data row with only the `Phone` and `StructuredName` mimetypes (since thats all we care about). We will get at least 1 row for each RawContact (that we care about). One row will be either a `StructuredName` or `Phone` row which is why we check the mimetype as we loop over the results and also why we check the contact id (to see if we are still reading data for the current contact).

If a RawContact has both `Phone` and `StructuredName` then we will get 1 row for the `StructuredName` and `n` rows for each of the `Phone`'s the RawContact has.